# Global typecast operator overload?

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm writing some 'portable' code (meaning that it targets 32- and 64-bit MSVC2k10 and GCC on Linux) in which I have, more or less:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
```

C-strings are always uint8; this is for string-processing reasons. Legacy code needs char compiled as signed, so I can't set compiler switches to default it to unsigned. But if I'm processing a string I can't very well index an array:

```
char foo[500];
char *ptr = (foo + 4);
*ptr = some_array_that_normalizes_it[*ptr];
```

You can't index an array with a negative number at run-time without serious consequences. Keeping C-strings unsigned allows for such easier protection from bugs.

I would really like to not have to keep casting (char *) every time I use a function that takes char *'s, and also stop duplicating class functions so that they take either. This is especially a pain because a string constant is implicitly passed as a char *

```
int foo = strlen("Hello");  // "Hello" is passed as a char *
```

I want all of these to work:

```
char foo[500] = "Hello!";   // Works
uint8 foo2[500] = "Hello!"; // Works
uint32 len = strlen(foo);   // Works
uint32 len2 = strlen(foo2); // Doesn't work
uint32 len3 = strlen((char *)foo2); // Works
```

There are probably caveats to allowing implicit type conversions of this nature, however, it'd be nice to use functions that take a char * without a cast every time.

So, I figured something like this would work:

```
operator char* (const uint8* foo) { return (char *)foo; }
```

However it does not. I can't figure out any way to make it work. I also can't find anything to tell me why there seems to be no way to do this. I can see the possible logic - implicit conversions like that could be a cause of FAR too many bugs - but I can't find anything that says "this will not work in C++" or why, or how to make it work (short of making uin8 a class which is ridiculous).

Comment: You can't write casts (or operators) that don't involve at least one user defined type

Comment: You have legacy code that uses `signed char`?? I very much doubt that...

Comment: why is making uint8 a class ridiculous? It's not any more ridiculous than having a bunch of stray global casting functions.

Comment: What's the compiler error message for the "uint32 len2 = strlen(foo2); // Doesn't work" line ?

Comment: C will implicitly convert them, can you use C?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Visual Studio has implicitly made char's signed unless you use a compiler flag for...well, since the legacy code started.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod making a single-byte type a class would fail in every way possible for the purposes of this typedef.

Comment: @Pubby nope, C++ code. I only used C examples so I don't have to show a class with duplicate overloaded member functions for (char *) and (uint8 *) arguments. I figured your imagination could fill those in...but I can provide an example if you'd like.

Comment: @OrgnlDave: I doubt that, because that would violate the C standard. `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are *required* to be distinct types.

Comment: @KerrekSB http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/01/char-types/ . It's true they're distinct, but modern compilers including Visual C++ 2010 default them to signed, for the reasons noted in that article.

Comment: As far as I understand the whole point of using unsigned char is to use an array for some kind of normalization procedure. But why can't you make a function like `char Normalize(char)`? Such function could use your normalization array and deal with negative argument values.

Comment: @Pavel when coding interfaces to classes one often wants to take a few kinds of strings. one can stick with an std::string which will automatically convert a char * but it can get "confused" about a uint8*, and fast string-processing inside std::strings is a bit annoying anyhow. thus one is presented with the problem of overloading a function 3 times. the first with an std::string that calls the char * overloaded version with the .c_str() from the std::string. the second with a char *. and the third with a uint8 *. let alone using things like strlen() like in the example not Normalize()

Comment: @PavelZhuravlev Moreover when doing a lot of specialized string-processing passing around C-strings (if you know what you're doing) is a lot more convenient than std::strings even with boost's algorithms to help massage things along. But I digress. The point of this isn't whether or not you can do things differently - it is whether or not you can do *what I asked*. :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of operator [ab]using, but thats what c++ is for right?

You can do the following:

```
const char* operator+(const uint8* foo) 
{ 
  return (const char *)foo; 
}

char* operator+(uint8* foo) 
{ 
  return (char *)foo; 
}
```

With those defined, your example from above:

```
uint32 len2 = strlen(foo2);
```

will become

```
uint32 len2 = strlen(+foo2);
```

It is not an automatic cast, but this way you have an easy, yet explicit way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

*Global cast(typecast) operator*, global assignment operator, global array subscript operator and global function call operator overloading are **not allowed in C++**.

MSVS C++ will be generate [C2801 errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28C2801%29;k%28VS.OUTPUT%29&rd=true) on them. [Look at wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) for list of C++ operators and them overloading rules.

Answer (score 0):

Both compilers you mention do have a "treat chars as unsigned" switch. Why not use that?

Comment: Breaking legacy code. Like I said in like...the second sentence.

Comment: Oh... I'm not sure about the nature of your program then. I thought you were writing something new! (like you said in the first sentence)